# Why the column type still "object" after I change it to numeric?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert the type of the column "sentiment" into numeric in the dataframe 'auto_df_dropped'. After code `pd.to_numeric(auto_df_dropped['sentiment'])`, nothing changing. It's still object? What's wrong here? Thanks!

## Before conversion:

```
auto_df_dropped.info()


......sentiment 6861 non-null object......
```

After Conversion:

```
auto_df_dropped.info()


......sentiment 6861 non-null object......
```

Comment: Pandas by default copies to a new df rather than making changes in place.

Comment: exact code snippet please

Comment: are you assigning the value back to sentiment? auto_df_dropped['sentiment'] = pd.to_numeric(auto_df_dropped['sentiment'])

Comment: I didn't. It works after assigned, Thanks so much!                                     
 sentiment                6861 non-null int64

Comment: can you give the head of the `sentiment` column

Comment: The problem solved after re-writing  "   auto_df_dropped[ 'sentiment'] = pd.to_numeric(auto_df_dropped['sentiment'])    "    The file is so big  that the head    would be copied randomly here,  Thanks!